# Can we use the same frame counter in A5/2

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher

Let we have three encoded messages with length $3*456$ bits in A5/2 encryption. Can we use the same frame counter in the encryption process or we must use different?

(E.g. this because in the below attack, attacker consider same 22 bits frame counter in the encryption and decryption algorithm with three messages. )

https://www.npag.fr/project-a52hacktool